# Is it possible to fuse DNA from two sperms into one sperm?

Tags: cell-biology, dna

Is it possible to fuse the DNA of two genetically different sperms into one singular sperm? In theory, half of the number of chromosomes in a normal sperm would come from one sperm and the other half could come from a separate sperm. In return, the fused sperm could fuse with a healthy egg cell for fertilization.

Answer (score 1):

It would be theoretically possible to engineer such a cell, but something very similar can occur in nature, two sperm cells can fertilise a single egg cell, resulting in a fetus with DNA from both. See [here](https://www.nature.com/news/2007/070326/full/070326-1.html)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! If it were to happen by engineering the cell, what process or pathway would theoretically be used to fuse the two sperms together?